# handle 404 exception and add static files in spring.web.resources spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, properties, graphql-java

I have an application spring-boot 2.6.

I'm handling 404 exception successfully with settings in `application.yml` below:

```yaml
spring:
    mvc:
        throw-exception-if-no-handler-found: true
    web:
        resources:
            add-mappings: false
```

That same application are using `altair-spring-boot-starter` that provide static files then I have got errors bellow:

```
No handler found for GET /vendor/altair/styles.css
No handler found for GET /vendor/altair/assets/img/logo_350.svg
No handler found for GET /vendor/altair/runtime-es2018.js
No handler found for GET /vendor/altair/main-es2018.js
No handler found for GET /vendor/altair/polyfills-es2018.js
No handler found for GET /vendor/altair/favicon.ico
```

If I turn `spring.web.resources.add-mappings` to `true` static files `altair` works but handle 404 dosen't work.

How to handle 404 exception spring boot and add satic files to mapping resources? Is there any way to do both on `application.yaml`?

Comment: Does path of `vendor` folder is `resources/static/vendor`?

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej from vendor github I got /`src/main/resources/static/vendor/altair/**` and `/src/main/resources/templates/altair.html`